# Why won't my pictures display in my bootstrap carousel?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I seem to have the Twitter Bootstrap carousel working properly as far as moving from picture to picture, however, the pictures are not displaying. I get the little image icon below and I see them slide across the page at the proper interval. I'm trying to get this working in my rails project on my local host. I'm new to programming and all of the searching I have done to try and uncover an answer to this has been unsuccessful. Below I included the HTML. Additionally, the images are in the source location listed below in the HTML and they are jpegs.

I'm trying to incorporate this into my home page if that makes any difference.  I appreciate the help.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
<!-- Carousel items -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="active item">
<img src="assets/images/pic1.jpg" alt></div>
<div class="item">
<img src="assets/images/pic2.jpg" alt></div>
<div class="item">
<img src="assets/images/pic3.jpg" alt></div>
</div>
<!-- Carousel nav -->
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This likely means that the path to your images is incorrect.  Try using an absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same problem of not having the images show up and I believe it has to due with the naming of each jpg file. In my HTML the image tags were pointing to pic.**jpg** but on my webhost, the files were named as pic.**JPG** and that actually makes a difference. So either rename it your html or the actual file and it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<img src="assets/images/pic1.jpg" alt>`, you should use the image helper:

```
<%= image_tag 'pic1.jpg' %>
```

If your pic1.jpg is in the app/assets/images folder, it will show then.

Comment: This was helpful because I neglected to use the helper so thank you for pointing that out and I have updated my code to include the image helper. This didn't correct the problem with the images actually showing up in the carousel.

Comment: For kicks I just tried a PNG image and that is working so I have just converted the files. Would love to know why the JPEG files were not working.

Comment: As JPEGs, the images were not showing up. I just had the broken picture looking icon coming up and they would slide across the screen at the proper interval I had setup. The PNG files are working just fine so that is the solution for now so I can keep learning, Thanks for the help.